# What do "depthSize" and "stencilSize" mean in setEGLConfigChooser()?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I don't understand what depthSize and stencilSize do in

```
setEGLConfigChooser(int redSize, int greenSize, int blueSize,
            int alphaSize, int depthSize, int stencilSize)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are precisions of depth and stencil buffers. If you choose configs with 0 values you will have no depth or stencil buffers.

Depth buffer is used for depth-testing of fragments and stencil buffer is used for masking fragments.

Here is a good explanation of purposes of both buffers: http://open.gl/depthstencils